# Loading a .ko file in userspace

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I would like to write a test harness for my Linux kernel module. I would therefore like to load the .ko file (kernel module) as if it was a .so file and then put it through its paces.

Are the .so and .ko file formats the same and if not is there a simple binary way (using tools like `objcopy`) to convert from a .ko to a .so?

Comment: Why not just change your make file so that it builds a .so instead of a .ko?

Comment: **API** for kernel modules and for user space libraries **differs** a lot. So loading the file compiled for the kernel into the user space would require to write additional libraries. As for differences in formats, kernel module loader actually uses several additional ELF sections in `.ko` file. (E.g., there is section contained `THIS_MODULE` structure).

Comment: APIs will either be stubbed out or setup for testing. As for dual build, why if it is not necessary.